# Can LyX automatically save the PDF output in the same folder in Windows 10?

Tags: lyx, pdf

I'm using LyX version 2.3.5.2 on Windows 10. When I click on the "Update" icon, I would prefer for the PDF output to go to the same directory as the LyX file instead of a temporary directory.  Is this possible?

Note: This is not a duplicate of the similar question at [Can LyX automatically save the PDF output in the same folder?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71110/can-lyx-automatically-save-the-pdf-output-in-the-same-folder).  That question applies to Mac OS.

Comment: The answer to the referenced question should work for all OS. I've checked it works on Linux.

Comment: scottkosty, Thanks for the comment.  I thought the other solution was OS specific, but it actually did work for me in Windows 10.

Comment: That's great it works! I updated the other solution to specify it should work for all OS.

Comment: Now that the answer explains it's valid for all OS, I've voted to mark this as closed.